# how can i send data to the selected client from server?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

i'm building a multithread example using sockets and threads in java. the sever will get multiple Socket at same time, and when i send a message from server, i want the socket from client to go back in order to what i give.
my understanding so far is to make ArrayList but i have no idea how to use it for my purpose.
can anyone help or give me any clue to solve this problem?

following is the code:

## //server socket to wait before accepting from client.

```
public class ServerSocketEntry {
   ServerSocket ssoc;
   Socket soc;
   ArrayList<Socket> arrSocket = new ArrayList<Socket>();
   private static final int port=4853;

public ServerSocketEntry(ServerManagement sm){
    try {
        ssoc = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Waiting");
        while(true){
            soc=ssoc.accept();
            arrSocket.add(soc);
            System.out.println("Accepted: "+soc);
            ServerSocketThread sth = new ServerSocketThread(soc,sm);
            sth.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerManagement sm = new ServerManagement();
    new ServerSocketEntry(sm);
}

}
```

## //threadClass using readObject(), writeObject() method.

```
public class ServerSocketThread extends Thread {
Socket soc;
ObjectOutputStream oos;
ObjectInputStream ois;
ServerManagement sm;
Food food;

public ServerSocketThread(Socket soc,ServerManagement sm) {
    this.soc=soc;
    this.sm=sm;
    try {
        ois= new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        oos= new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run(){
    Command com;
    while(true){
        try {
            com = (Command) ois.readObject();
            if(com.getCommand()==Command.Member_Check){
                Member member = (Member) com.getObj();
                System.out.println("thread: "+member);
                if(sm.checkMember(member)){
                    com.setCommand(Command.Command_OK);
                }else{
                    com.setCommand(Command.Command_Fail);
                }
            }else if(com.getCommand()==Command.LogIn_Check){
                Member member = (Member) com.getObj();
                if(sm.checkLogIn(member)){
                    com.setCommand(Command.Command_OK);
                }else{
                    com.setCommand(Command.Command_Fail);
                }
            }else if(com.getCommand()==Command.Food_Check){
                ArrayList<Food> serverArrFood = com.getFoodOrder();
                if(sm.checkFood(serverArrFood)){
                    com.setCommand(Command.Command_OK);
                }else{
                    com.setCommand(Command.Command_Fail);
                }
            }
            oos.writeObject(com);
            oos.flush();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You have to use the socket that is connected to the client you want to send to. It's just a data structure problem, and a trivial one at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you may use a hash map to store the connected clients and it will be easy to get a specific client from the map and send message to that. Use a nickname of the client as the key and socket as a value at the time when a new client connects to the sever. Put these values into the map. For Example:

```
Map<String, Socket> clients = new HashMap();
clients.put(nickname, clientSocket);
```

While writing simply get that specific client by its key.

```
clients.get(nickname);
```

and write to its output stream. When one client sends message to a specific client, it should send the receiver's nickname as part of the message to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. it's a very kind answer and helpful for my learning project!!